# UIScrollView for a smaller UIView inside main UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, constraints

I'm having trouble getting this working, best explained what i am trying to do with this image of my storyboard.

[image: Storyboard]

The main goal is to make that container scrollable, with its size dependent on the view controller that gets added into it via code.

Here is how i have laid out my views.

[image: Layout of Views]

Obviously my constraints are what is messing me up, but not exactly sure how to get them to behave as expected, I've tried pinning the container to the scroll view and then the scroll view to the main view. The screen appears how i want but it just doesn't scroll.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone wondering how to do this, i finally figured out how to do it after a lot of trial and error.
Basically what I did was remove the container view from the storyboard, set my constraints on the scroll view as i normally would:

[image: Constraints]

and then added a container view as a subview of the scroll view in code:

```
var containerView : UIView!
var currentViewController: UIViewController

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.containerView = UIView()
        self.scrollView.addSubview(self.containerView)
}
```

To swap between different view controllers using my UISegmentControl and have the scroll view scroll the content no matter how large the new view controller is i added the following code in my UISegmentControl functions

```
@IBAction func segControlValueChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let vc = viewControllerForSelectedSegmentIndex(sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        self.currentViewController!.view.removeFromSuperview()
        self.currentViewController!.removeFromParentViewController()      
        displayCurrentTab(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
    }
}

func displayCurrentTab(tabIndex: Int){
    if let vc = viewControllerForSelectedSegmentIndex(tabIndex) {
        self.addChildViewController(vc)
        self.containerView.addSubview(vc.view)
        vc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        vc.view.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: vc.view.frame.height) //had to add this because otherwise for some reason my new vc width would not increase or decrease to its parent view
        self.currentViewController = vc
        self.scrollView.contentSize = vc.view.frame.size
    }
}

func viewControllerForSelectedSegmentIndex(index: Int) -> UIViewController {
    //instantiate and return your view controller here
}
```

Some other notes:

- I disabled "resize view from NIB" in storyboard for all my view controllers i plan to add to the container

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible from your question & screenshots to determine what constraints you actually do have set up.  And your question doesn't even particularly make it clear whether your constraints are behaving properly (aside from the scroll view not scrolling, which may or may not be related to constraints).

First, we need to make sure our constraints are hooked up correctly.  The container view for which you're going to put a scroll view into should have four constraints.  One for each side, left & right, pinning it to those edges.  One for the bottom to pin it to the toolbar, and one for the top to pin it to your top views.  It doesn't need any more constraints.  Now, the toolbar at the bottom and your views at the top need to have their constraints set up so that they have a constant height per device/orientation, and does not care about the size of the container view.  If your constraints are set up correctly, then resizing this view in your interface builder file should be changing the size of the container view.  If this isn't happening, head back to the drawing board because something isn't quite right.

If you are confident your constraints are set up correctly, there are a few other things about the scrollview itself that could prevent scrolling.

First, check the most obvious.  Is the scrolling enabled property set to `true` on your scroll view?  If not... of course it's not going to scroll.

The other thing that could be happening is that your content view is not larger than the scroll view.  Make sure that you've properly set up autolayout for the contents of the scroll view, otherwise the content view will not be larger than the scroll view, and no scrolling will be happening.

Comment: Well i was just after general tips on which constraints would be needed to do something like this, the ones in my photo were probably wrong so i didn't see a point in showing them. 
So the scroll view should be inside the container and not the other way around like i have in my photo?, okay ill see how that goes and let you know